# Парсинг динамического сайта, контента, html. Установка Selenium и Appium

Tags: java, android, парсер, selenium, appium

Я хочу создать клиент для сайта под android (android studio 3.0.1). У этого сайта динамический HTML, и мой любимый Jsoup с этим не справляется. Поискал в интернете и нашел selenium и appium, httpunit. Но установить их у меня никак не получается! Каждая из них выдает миллион ошибок.
Я пробовал установить Selenium, скачав библиотеку с http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/ (3.8.1), сунул jar в проект/libs, сделал Add as library, но когда я начинаю сборку выдает все время разные ошибки, непонятно на что он жалуется)) Иногда такие ошибки

Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild'.

> Conflict with dependency 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305' in project ':app'. Resolved versions for app (1.3.9) and test app (2.0.1) differ. See https://d.android.com/r/tools/test-apk-dependency-conflicts.html for details.

или такие ошибки:
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process C:\Users\AsUs.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-expression\5.0.2.RELEASE\246bf50b5b46379041d333b4a46a01a7aea0b788\spring-expression-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar
>   Error:com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: invalid opcode ba (invokedynamic requires --min-sdk-version >= 26)
>   Error:com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Error while dexing org/springframework/expression/spel/support/ReflectiveMethodResolver.class
>   Error:com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process C:\Users\AsUs.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-expression\5.0.2.RELEASE\246bf50b5b46379041d333b4a46a01a7aea0b788\spring-expression-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar
>   Warning:Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class

Так я уже пробовал:

```
android {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
    }
}
```

Я пробовал установить Appium вот так:

```
compile 'io.appium:java-client:6.0.0-BETA2'
```

Я пробовал установить Selenium и Appium вместе, но все равно не получается. Я не знаю что значат эти ошибки. Может они не совместимы с Android Studio? Предложите какой нибудь парсер для динамичсеких сайтов. Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: Нашел ответ? Если да поделись.

Answer (score 0):

Установил `Appium` в `AndroidStudio` так как сказано на их [GitHub](https://github.com/appium/java-client):

- В файле `build.gradle` (который в `app`) дописываем между `android` и `dependencies`:

```
    android{
        ...
    }
    
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
    
    dependencies {
        ...
    }
```

- А в `dependencies` добавляем (вместо `7.5.1` ставим последнюю версию):

```
  implementation 'com.github.appium:java-client:7.5.1'
```